# How can I get the complete list from \showlists

Tags: tex-core

This is the code.

```
I'm stupid. I'm stupid. I'm stupid. \showlists
```

And this what I get from `\showlists`

```
\### horizontal mode entered at line 1  
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0  
\tenrm I  
\tenrm '  
\tenrm m  
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111  
etc.  
spacefactor 3000  
\### vertical mode entered at line 0  
prevdepth ignored
```

My questions is: how can I get the complete list? That is, how can I make TeX elaborate on that "etc." stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters to act on are `\showboxdepth` and `\showboxbreadth`.

```
Depth: \the\showboxdepth; breadth: \the\showboxbreadth

I'm stupid. I'm stupid. I'm stupid. \showlists

\eject

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen \showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

I'm stupid. I'm stupid. I'm stupid. \showlists

\bye
```

The output is

[image]

In the log file the second `\showlists` will generate, among other things,

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 9
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\tenrm I
\tenrm '
\tenrm m
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
\tenrm s
\tenrm t
\tenrm u
\tenrm p
\tenrm i
\tenrm d
\tenrm .
\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
\tenrm I
\tenrm '
\tenrm m
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
\tenrm s
\tenrm t
\tenrm u
\tenrm p
\tenrm i
\tenrm d
\tenrm .
\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
\tenrm I
\tenrm '
\tenrm m
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
\tenrm s
\tenrm t
\tenrm u
\tenrm p
\tenrm i
\tenrm d
\tenrm .
\glue 4.44444 plus 4.99997 minus 0.37036
spacefactor 3000
### vertical mode entered at line 0
prevdepth 1.94444
```

`\maxdimen`, when used in the context of an assignment to a count register is coerced to an integer (the maximum allowed positive number).

Comment: `\maxdimen` is `2^30-1` in `sp` units (`"3FFFFFFF`), whereas the maximal allowed positive number is `2^31-1`. (`"7FFFFFFF`).